# Java JSONArray and Parallelization of iteration

Tags: java, json, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a piece of code that I would like to parallelize as they are independent operations -

```
        List<StockQuote> topGainers = new ArrayList<StockQuote>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

        //Parallelize the for loop
        for(int iter=0;iter<dataArray.size();iter++) {
            JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(iter);
            System.out.println(temp.get("symbol"));
            //getQuote function has network calls. 
            //Serial implementation makes it take too much time
            topGainers.add(this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol")));
        }

        return topGainers;
```

How can this piece of code be parallelized? Is ArrayList and its Add operation threadsafe?

I tried this -

```
        int size = dataArray.size();
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(size);
        forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
        IntStream.range(1, size).parallel().filter( (IntPredicate)i -> { 
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);
            System.out.println(temp.get("symbol"));
            try {
                System.out.println(temp.get("symbol"));
                topGainers.add(this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return true;}));
```

I got the topGainers array as empty

Comment: @luk2302 the getQuote function has network calls. Hence parallelization helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` is not a `Synchronized` collection. So, `ArrayList#add` is not thread-safe. Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead which is thread safe. Java-8 provided us some excellent feature one of those is `parallelStream` over the collection. So you can take advantage of that. However, you are always free to create your own thread pool and execute the task if it gives you more benefit.

Below example may help you

```
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<StockQuote> topGainers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    dataArray.parallelStream().forEach(e->{
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(iter);
        System.out.println(temp.get("symbol"));
        //getQuote function has network calls. 
        //Serial implementation makes it take too much time
        topGainers.add(this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol")));
    });
```

You cloud also use `Collections#synchronizedList`.

Answer from the question 1 from comment: `dataArray.parallelStream().forEach` will iterate over the list in parallel.

Answer to your question 2 from comment :

```
   dataArray.parallelStream().forEach(e->{
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(iter);
        System.out.println(temp.get("symbol"));
        //getQuote function has network calls. 
        //Serial implementation makes it take too much time
        if (some condition here) {
           throw new YourException("Your exception messge");
         }
        topGainers.add(this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol")));
    });
```

Comment: iter is missing. Is e the object ?

Comment: small doubt - if i want to throw back an exception if one operation breaks here, what do i do? I tried setting a flag that changes it to true. but this lambda can only take final variables

Comment: @PrateekNarendra please refer to my answer. I have edited it with your answer.

Comment: lets assume that `this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol"))` could throw an exception. Thanks for the help though. But im unable to throw back an exception

Comment: I am still not clear about your requirement. If this.getQuote((String)temp.get("symbol")) throws an exception it will automatically propagate.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra what do you want when an Exception is thrown? Do you want to retry the same operation which throws the exception? Or you want to terminate the iteration or simply it for logging purpose?

Comment: I want to terminate the whole function and throw back an exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167050/discussion-between-amit-bera-and-prateek-narendra).

Comment: @PrateekNarendra The answer to your question may be big and need a lot of input from your side. So, to maintain the etiquette of SO I will suggest, please add a new question with your new requirements.